# Get a volume label from Java on linux

Tags: java, linux

Is there any way to read volume label in Java program on Linux?

I've found sample of doing that at http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0455.html
It uses FileSystemView class, but it seems working only on Windows. On Linux for /dev/sdb1 it returns sdb1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to exist portable way to do it in java. You will need to write separate code for each OS.

For linux you will need to run proper system command depending on filesystem type and then parse the output.

To read label from cdrom:

```
$ volname /dev/cdrom
Ubuntu 10.10 i386
```

To read label from ntfs partition (`-f` needed for mounted filesystem):

```
$ ntfslabel -f /dev/sda5 2>/dev/null
DATA
```

To read FAT (vfat) label:

```
dosfslabel /dev/sdb
SD card
```

**Note:** You will need read permissions for devices you're accessing.